# Grid registration issue converting from GeoTIFF to Esri ASCII Raster format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, gdal, geotiff-tiff, esri-ascii-raster

I've got a 3 arc second digital terrain model represented as a 32-bit GeoTIFF that looks like this:

```
$ gdal_info gom03_v1_0.tif

Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: gom03_v1_0.tif
Size is 10200, 7800
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["WGS 84",
    DATUM["WGS_1984",
        SPHEROID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
            AUTHORITY["EPSG","7030"]],
        AUTHORITY["EPSG","6326"]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
    AUTHORITY["EPSG","4326"]]
Origin = (-71.499580383300781,45.999583333330001)
Pixel Size = (0.000833333333333,-0.000833333333332)
Metadata:
  TIFFTAG_SOFTWARE=nc2geotiff
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  ( -71.4995804,  45.9995833) ( 71d29'58.49"W, 45d59'58.50"N)
Lower Left  ( -71.4995804,  39.4995833) ( 71d29'58.49"W, 39d29'58.50"N)
Upper Right ( -62.9995804,  45.9995833) ( 62d59'58.49"W, 45d59'58.50"N)
Lower Right ( -62.9995804,  39.4995833) ( 62d59'58.49"W, 39d29'58.50"N)
Center      ( -67.2495804,  42.7495833) ( 67d14'58.49"W, 42d44'58.50"N)
Band 1 Block=10200x1 Type=Float32, ColorInterp=Gray
```

Note that the `AREA_OR_POINT` attribute is set to `AREA`.

When I convert this to ARC ASCII Grid format using GDAL:

```
gdal_translate gom03_v1_0.tif -of AAIGrid test.asc
```

and look at the top of the resulting ASCII file, I see:

```
$ more test.asc

ncols        10200
nrows        7800
xllcorner    -71.499580383301
yllcorner    39.499583333335
cellsize     0.000833333333
 315.814208984375 314.712371826171875 ...
```

These `xllcorner`,`yllcorner` values are the same as the GeoTIFF `Lower Left` values above.  From the [official description of the ESRI ASCII Raster Format](http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisengine/java/GP_ToolRef/spatial_analyst_tools/esri_ascii_raster_format.htm), however, either `xllcorner`,`yllcorner` or `xllcenter`,`yllcenter` can be specified.  Since the GeoTIFF values represented AREA (not POINT), isn't the specification of `xllcorner` and `yllcorner` incorrect?

Shouldn't the ASCII file in this case really read as below?

```
$ more test.asc

ncols        10200
nrows        7800
xllcenter    -71.499580383301
yllcenter    39.499583333335
cellsize     0.000833333333
 315.814208984375 314.712371826171875 ...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the `xllcorner` and `yllcorner` specification is correct, because
the GeoTIFF specifies `Corner Coordinates` (not center coordinates).